# AKS ingress address is empty. Grafana not being exposed through ingress

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have my AKS cluster where I am running my application without any problem. I have two deployments (backend-frontend) and I am using a service of type ClusterIP and an ingress controller to expose them publicly. I am trying to do the same with my Grafana deployment but it's not working. I am getting 404 error. If I go and execute the port forward I can access it over http://localhost:3000 and login successfully. The failure part is with ingress as it's created but with an empty address. I have three ingresses two of them shows the public IP in Address column and they are accessible through the URL while grafana url is not working.

Here is my Grafana Ingress:

```
 kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: loki-grafana-ingress
  namespace: ingress-basic
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 6.7.0
    helm.sh/chart: grafana-5.7.10
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: loki
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-basic
  
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - xxx.xxx.me
      secretName: sec-tls
  rules:
    - host: xxx.xxx.me
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: loki-grafana
              servicePort: 80
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Attached are the Ingresses created:
[Ingresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Owli.png)

Grafana Service

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: loki-grafana
  namespace: ingress-basic
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 6.7.0
    helm.sh/chart: grafana-5.7.10
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: loki
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-basic

spec:
  ports:
    - name: service
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
  clusterIP: 10.0.189.19
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

When doing `kubectl port-forward --namespace ingress-basic service/loki-grafana 3000:80`
[Grafana_localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAPp9.png)

[Grana_URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jzLj.png)

Comment: Show me the nginx ingress logs

Comment: @Matt Thanks man. I check the logs and it was my nginx ingress failing. So I removed it and added new one and it worked.